# Collision system not working

Tags: java, collision

I am making a small game, with a friend. Now, I have a camera-system, I am walking by basicly just changing x and y values of environment objects. Example:

```
    public void move(){
    if(player.up){
        enemyposy += player.speedY;
        hostageposy += player.speedY;
        grassy += player.speedY;
        ammoboxy += player.speedY;
        healthkity += player.speedY;
        helipady += player.speedY;
        bushy += player.speedY;
    }
```

This will move all those objects, down when you press the up button, so it creates an illusion that the player is moving, which it isn't. Now, I tried and create a collision system by doing this:

```
    public void checkCollision(){
    if(player.getBounds().intersects(enemy.getBounds())){
        System.out.println("Colliding with Enemy");
        healthdown.start();
    }else{
        healthdown.stop();
    }
```

But, when I go to the enemy, and touch it, it won't react like it's touching, it's not saying "Colliding with Enemy.", however I AM in the player. Can somebody perhaps tell me why it's not responding, and give me a solution on how to solve it?

getBounds method:

```
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(getX(),getY(), 20, 20);
}
```

player getBounds is exactly the same.

intersects is an already implemented method.

boolean java.awt.Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle r)

Determines whether or not this Rectangle and the specified Rectangle intersect. Two rectangles intersect if their intersection is nonempty.

Parameters:
r the specified Rectangle
Returns:
true if the specified Rectangle and this Rectangle intersect; false otherwise.

Comment: how are implemented your getBounds() and intersects() method ?

Comment: Use your debugger; without the source code, we can't debug this for you...

Comment: where are you calling checkCollision()?

Comment: I simply cannot fathom how you can expect anyone to know what's wrong based on the information you have given.

Comment: @Mr E: Well, what do you need more than this then?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your initial version that you were using the existing Rectangle class. As others have said, you need to debug, or at the very least print out the rectangles and see if the numbers look right.

Comment: @Stan we would need *a lot* more information. How do we know where and when you update the coordinations of a player/enemy. Maybe it isn't updated. Maybe player.speedY is 0. Maybe the player and enemy travelled in different directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you show you don't update player.x so player.getX won't change. The same for enemy :)

Comment: I'm updating the move(); in my game loop, and also i'm checking the collisions in my game loop. It's not that.